# "'undefined' is not an object" error on audio ended property

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm using the audio element in HTML5 and checking to see if the played audio has ended. Everything seems to work fine but my inspector in Safari 7 is reporting an error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'audioPlayer.ended')

Outside of any function, I have the audio player variable stated:

```
var audioPlayer;
```

In my window.onload function, I define the audioPlayer variable as the audioPlayer element:

```
window.onload = function() {

     audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
}
```

In my html's body element, I have the audio element defined with the proper id:

```
<audio id='audioPlayer'>
  <source id='MP3AudioSource' source='North Pole Promise Clip 1.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
Please update your browser to support audio playback.
</audio>
```

If I open up the error details, it also reports my timerVariable as an "anonymous function"

```
var timerVar = setInterval(function(){timer()}, 10);
```

**UPDATE**

I found out this was a setInterval function defined outside of window.onload, and the function the interval calls has elements that it depends on using that may not be defined until the page is full loaded.

Comment: btw `function(){timer()}` could be just `timer` :-)

Comment: Try closing your `<source>` tag

Comment: Thanks nicael, it got rid of the anonymous function error by changing that, but I still have the other error. Closing my source tag does nothing.

Comment: @minseong: `<source>` doesn't need a closing tag.